# Md-card padding

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Hello i am using angular material. And i create an md-card with the following code:

```
<div  layout="row">
<md-card class="col-md-4">
  <div class="md-card-image" style="background-color: #40DEC8; text-align: center">
    <h1 style="color: white;">Title</h1>
  </div>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input ng-model="detailsCtrl.parking.name">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>District</label>
    <input ng-model="detailsCtrl.parking.district">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea ng-model="detailsCtrl.parking.description" columns="1" md-maxlength="500"></textarea>
  </md-input-container>
</md-card>
```

and the result is this:
[image]

Is there any way to remove the white space (padding) shown with the black arrows and fill it with the green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the card that adds the padding, but it is the (I assume bootstrap) class `col-md-4`. A solution is to move your `col-md-4` outside the `md-card`, like this:

```
<!-- The padding will be on this div instead of the card -->
<div class="col-md-4"> 
    <md-card>
        <div class="md-card-image" style="background-color: #40DEC8; text-align: center">
            <h1 style="color: white;">Title</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Other html -->
    </md-card>
</div>
```